# Spring Hibernate JSF integration Status 404

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jsf

I am going to integrate `hibernate 4` and `Spring 4` and `jsf 2.2` with `jdk1.8` and `tomcat` in `netbeans`.

Here is my project Structure:

[image]

Here is `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
        xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
        xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="sajjad.htlo"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/obs" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="2323" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" 
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
          p:packagesToScan="com.sajjad"
          p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties"/>

    <util:properties id="hibernateProperties">
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Detect @Transactional Annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

And here is `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
          p:suffix=".xhtml" />

    <bean name="indexController"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

And here is `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is `hibernate.cfg.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/obs</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">209854</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>

    <mapping class="sajjad.htlo.book.Books" />
    <mapping class="sajjad.htlo.customer.Customers" />
    <mapping class="sajjad.htlo.order.Orders" />
    <mapping class="sajjad.htlo.order.OrderItems" />

</session-factory>
```

And finally here is `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sajjad</groupId>
    <artifactId>OnlineBookStore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>OnlineBookStore</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I have `two` problem:

`First`, i am worry about some additional or overlapped libraries added in maven, since it populate from several examples i saw them in different websites.

`Second`, I have no error in runtime, but i can't access to `Login.xhtml` page (`which is welcome page`).

`tomcat console`:

```
    Mar 22, 2015 2:29:10 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Mar 22 02:28:27 GMT+03:30 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:10 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Mar 22 02:28:24 GMT+03:30 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:10 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/OnlineBookStore] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:10 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/OnlineBookStore] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeploy
INFO: Undeploying context [/OnlineBookStore]
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\OnlineBookStore.xml
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:11 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Sajjad\Desktop\OnlineBookStore\target\OnlineBookStore-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://mojarra.dev.java.net/mojarra_ext is already defined
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: 
        http://java.sun.com/jsf/html
     is already defined
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core is already defined
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:13 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:13 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Mar 22 02:29:13 GMT+03:30 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@34588ee] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1550 ms
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:14 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '/OnlineBookStore'
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:15 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:15 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/OnlineBookStore/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:16 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:16 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:16 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Mar 22 02:29:16 GMT+03:30 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:16 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:16 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/index.htm] onto handler 'indexController'
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:16 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 125 ms
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\OnlineBookStore.xml has finished in 4,770 ms
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:16 AM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/OnlineBookStore]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:16 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/OnlineBookStore/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

`tomcat log`:

```
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 22, 2015 2:29:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
```

I saw [this](http://www.journaldev.com/4096/primefaces-spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial) and [this](http://www.journaldev.com/4058/primefaces-spring-4-with-jpa-hibernate-eclipselink-example-tutorial) , But nowhere uses `controller` class, and i have no idea of how can i use `Controller` class and jsf `managedBean` class together correctly.

I have this simple controller class in `com.customer` package:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    @RequestMapping("/Login.xhtml")
    public ModelAndView loginRequest(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Login");
        return model;
    }
}
```

And this jsf `bean`:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class RegistrationBean implements Serializable {

private String username;
private String password;
private String email;
//getter/setters and registration method
}
```

Now, this is the result of application running:

```
HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
```

Comment: What are you doing with `@RequestMapping("/Login.xhtml")` in a Spring controller annotated with `@Controller`? It is used, when you strictly use  Spring MVC which in turn cannot and should not be used with JSF and that `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file is useless while using JSF on top of Spring.

Comment: @Tiny So you'r mean is that i should control requests in `jsf` bean instead of `controller`, Correct?

Comment: Yes, if you intend to use JSF on top Spring. They will all be Spring managed beans (`@Controller`/`@Component`, `Scope("scope")`. View scope is unavailable. You need to create it on your own). Not JSF managed beans (`@ManagedBean`) or use CDI (`@Named`), if you like (There is no Spring MVC involvement at all).

Comment: @Tiny Thanks, Are you have some example of integrating of these three frameworks?

Comment: I never found canonical sources for Spring/JSF integration as of now though there might be some which I am unfamiliar with. I had been misleading for a long time in the past. Currently, [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/) is an example that leads to older Spring/JSF versions but the fundamental is the same for later versions too. There mentioned, "***Mixed use of both JSF and Spring annotations are working fine** but it look weird and duplicated – `@Component` and `@ManagedBean` together*".

Comment: Beware of the text in bold letters in the preceding comment. They actually do not work together.They are governed by their own contexts. So, never mix annotations. **Either** have Spring **or** JSF manage your beans - not both (currently `@Controller` - a specialization of `@Component`). Later, when you need a view scope, Spring does not provide a view scope out of the box. You need to create it on your own, [example](http://blog.harezmi.com.tr/spring-view-scope-for-jsf-2-users/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pushed fully configured project wiht JSF/HIbernate/Spring, please have a look it will solve all problems
[JSF/hibernate/Spring](https://github.com/armdev/JSF2.2-Spring4-Hibernate4-MySQL)

Comment: I am waiting to completely push the project, Thanks.